# How should I handle grounding & neutral bonding when replacing my sub-panel?

Tags: subpanel, replacement, grounding-and-bonding, old-house

Current subpanel was installed in the early 70s. We *think we* need to replace it as lights are not working (very dim, flickering/fading in/out) - *we suspect an open neutral*.

How do we wire in a new panel? We have a 3-wire feeder. Ground/neutral is the same bus on the subpanel currently. Do we need grounding rods? Bonded ground & neutral?

Subpanel is probably 200 feet away, separate building (barn), no other metallic items connecting it to main building.

Other results from here/around the web are confusing me.

Edit: It is a 3-wire feeder with a bare stranded neutral. There is no ground, but we plan to place a grounding rod. I know, or think I know, that not to bond if it was a 4-wire feeder. We will measure voltage when we get a chance, sorry.

Comment: Tons of unknowns - fill in as much as you can: Where? Country/State/City; What kind of feeder do you have? 3-wire buried cable? 3 wires through conduit? Something else?; What kind of subpanel do you have now (pictures would help)?; What is the feed breaker in the main panel for the subpanel?

Comment: Michigan - I think it was 4-wire hanging, but it was damaged and became a 3-wire, or something like that. Subpanel has 2 60A? Cylindrical fuses as the main disconnect, 2 cylindrical fuses for a range, and 4 30A screw-type fuses for circuits. I think it was an old house panel or something, I do not know. There is a plug in a circuit that has it's neutral and ground on the neutral bus. Feeding breaker is 100 I think. New panel is 125A subpanel.

Comment: Well, that's enough to determine that you (a) have some serious issues to be fixed and (b) really do want to **replace** the subpanel rather than just fix it. The pros will come along and ask more questions and likely give some very detailed answers. Anything else you can provide in terms of actual loads (lights? tools? heat?) and about the main panel and about accessibility to run a new overhead cable and/or to trench for underground cable or conduit, etc. will be helpful.

Comment: A new trenched line is planned as soon as money appears for it, probably after other more important things are taken care of. Have no idea about main panel, neighbor's house. Load: like 3 lights, a compressor, some outlets, and a tractor (block heater, and the occasional battery charger). Our goal is to just get lights working, with a future rewire in the works, cloth wire was mainly used, some romex can be found, it's an old install. There is plans to expand barn, so additional lights/outlets. heat lamps for chicks in the spring though.

Comment: I think it is going to come down to two separate, but related, questions: 1 - What is the status of the existing wire between the buildings? It may be fixable, or it might need total replacement. 2 - What is the status of the subpanel? Old is not *necessarily* "must replace", but once you *start* replacing, you need to upgrade to modern standards - e.g., GFCI, ground/neutral separate, etc.

Comment: The light would flicker, so we cleaned wires/screws, which worked for the night. So we then removed the switch and used romex from panel, to existing wire, light still flickers, so we connected the light socket to the romex, still flickered, light socket to circuit side of panel, still flickered, but it didn't flicker on the feeder side. Air compressor seems to run with no problems, just the lights were having issues. I was told the neutral feeder was hit and broke, and was fixed somehow. The feeder wires are 2 blacks and a bare stranded wire, that I can see, that feed the panel.

Comment: Running new feeder is out of the question unless you want to make a donation... Lol. This post only formed as we were unsure if we bond the neutral/ground on the replacement panel or not. I think a good answer that I might be asking is: how do we best swap these panels, and wire them.

Comment: If neutral is out, that **must** be resolved for safety. What voltage do you get on each circuit? If neutral is out, likely to be at an end and not that the wire needs to be replaced. Sounds like you have a 3 wire service feeder - those can have bare stranded neutral but normally used for a subpanel.

Comment: Yes to ground rods. Yes gfci for receptacles but not needed for circuits that only have hardwired lights.

Comment: Can you measure the voltages on each leg of the incoming feeder to the subpanel please? This sounds like a busted neutral in the overhead feeder...also, can you post a photo of said overhead wiring?

Comment: Pictures, pictures, pictures! Take pics of the main panel, the sub panel, all the labels on the sub panel. Pics of the wiring where you think it was broken then repaired. Pics with the covers on and with the covers off. Nice, clear, focused pics, then [edit] them into your question. Drag the pics into the question, or use the "sun & mountain" icon to browse to them - the site will upload them to their own hosting service & embed the pics in the question for you.

Comment: Troy, **replacing a subpanel probably will not fix your underlying problem** which you should identify before buying anything.  While I'm strongly in favor of people having really big panels so you never run out of spaces (spaces are dirt cheap), I have no interest in *tricking you into doing that* by pretending it'll solve a problem it won't solve, or forcing you to spend crazy money to do it.  I want you to spend $30 more, not $300 lol.

Comment: I did an edit to focus it enough to meet our rules - a few distant questions went away.  Please [edit] in pics -- by the way it really helps to [register] your account to an email/password, or tie it to Facebook or Google account.  That will *assure* you can continue to interact as the question owner, and allows you to log in via other devices (e.g. the phone you'd take the pix with lol).

Comment: What type of panel? Is this a federal pacific stablock? Or Zinsco panel? Both of these panels were common in the 70’s and could be the root cause, I saw cloth wire so I am guessing copper wire also. But aluminum feeder is possible.